# How to access Apache Solr's Velocity Search UI

Tags: solr, velocity

I have just completed the Solr Quick Start Guide, and got it up and running, with the admin user interface seemingly working. Likewise, searches using curl (following the instructions in the guide) also works as expected, as do a very basic web find interface  ( http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted_shard2_replica1/browse )

However, when I try to access the Velocity sample search UI mentioned in the reference, I get page not found 404 message. The reference doc is located at:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Velocity+Search+UI

and it claims that the sample search UI should be accessible at

http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse

I'm guessing it may have something to do about the fact that I, following the instructions, created a sharded setup.

Is there any way I can access the sample UI in this setup, or is it something else I am missing.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I was just testing this myself - as I don't know anything about Velocity! - but what I did was in my core, which is named "link" I renamed the "conf" to "xxxconf" - just so it wouldn't load.

Then I copied the "conf" folder from the "sampletechproducts" in the "configset" folder.

At that point I was able to go to my path:
http://localhost:8983/solr/link/browse
And it was working - about 80%…lol But, working enough to know that Velocity looks good…I'm just now searching for how to actually use it - which how I found your post.

I'm sure you could also just create a new core, call it "techtest" or some such, and copy the whole "sampletechproducts" folder contents into it.

Hope this helps as I have been having a nightmare of a time trying to get Solr configured the way I want!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

For a vanilla download use this command to setup the core and velocity ui

`bin/solr -e techproducts`

Answer (score 0):

As [randomg213](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8135254/randomg213) mentioned you can use `bin/solr -e techproducts`, but it only configures a bundled example of Solr named techproducts.
Reviewing https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#the-standard-query-parser got me to the conclusion that you can use following link for a simple static term search:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<Your core name/index name>/select?q=<Your search term>
```

can be any core/index you have built like: myindex or mycore
 can be any word or sentence you are looking for.
Consider changing the port if you specified any port different from 8983 for your core/index, for example:

```
http://localhost:8994/solr/myindex/select?q=annachapman
```